# Проблемы с доступом к файлу системы

Tags: ос, права

Случилось так, багнулась установка Eset, в итоге теперь ни установить заного не могу, ни удалить установленного, мол доступа нету. Работаю через администратора, пытаюсь сделать его владельцем папки с установленным антивирусником, однако не даёт следующего. Уже несколько недель без антивирусника живу, да вот проблемы стали появляться

Comment: Можно попробовать их [утилиту](https://www.esetnod32.ru/download/utilities/av_remover/) для удаления

Comment: Не видит он его.... А файлы то там есть

Comment: *Работаю через администратора, пытаюсь сделать его владельцем папки с установленным антивирусником, однако не даёт* Используя [psexec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec), запустите интерактивно консоль от имени системы и выполните нужные действия. Но сперва тщательно прочистите реестр от любых упоминаний этого каталога и файлов в нём - а то можно запросто сделать из операционной системы большой кирпич...